# jQuery keyUp never fires

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keyup

Simple code:

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-    
     latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#target").keyup(function() {
            alert("Handler for .keyup() called.");
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <input id="target" type="text">
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

I can type in the input field, but no alert is shown. I have also tried this in Chrome and Mozilla.

Comment: Wrap your jQuery code in Document ready `$(function(){..});`

Comment: Ou sht. I also thought so but I didn't see any error in debugger like ("No element with such ID found") but there was nothing so I dropped it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run the keyup function after the document finishes loading

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-    
 latest.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#target").keyup(function() {
        alert("Handler for .keyup() called.");
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <input id="target" type="text">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```